# Constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data, when trying to test a service using xUnit. What does this mean and where is my issue?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my service(s).

I'm just trying to get the hang of a simple one, just testing the `GetAsync` method of my service, using xUnit and Moq.

Here's my code:

```
namespace HRB_Server.Tests.Services
{
    public class PhaseServiceTest
    {
        private readonly Mock<IRepository<Phase>> _repository;
        private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
        private readonly Mock<HrbContext> _context;

        public PhaseServiceTest()
        {
            _repository = new Mock<IRepository<Phase>>();
            _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
            _context = new Mock<HrbContext>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void GetPhase_ActivePhaseObject_PhaseShouldExist()
        {
            // Arrange
            var newGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            var phase = GetSamplePhase(newGuid);

            _repository.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(It.IsAny<Guid>()))
                .Returns(GetSamplePhase(newGuid));

            var phaseService = new PhaseService(_repository.Object, _mapper.Object, _context.Object);

            // Act
            var result = phaseService.GetAsync(newGuid);

            // Assert (expected, actual)
            Assert.Equal(phase.Id, result.Id);
    }
}
```

This code produces the following error:

`The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: IMapper mapper, HrbContext context`

My "real" service requires 3 objects, the IRepository, the automapper, and the context.

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

Here's my IRepository class:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id);
}
```

Here's my Context class:

```
public class HrbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    // DBsets are here...

     public HrbContext(DbContextOptions<HrbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         ... 
    }
}
```

The Mapper class is really the "AutoMapper" one, from the Nuget Package.

Comment: Can you please share your `Mapper` object, `HrbContext` object & `IRepository` interface?

Comment: Yes, I have added them to my original post :)!

Comment: Is it because my "context" object takes constructor parameters?

Comment: Correct, I've added an answer to highlight this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because your `HrbContext` has a constructor with 2 parameters, which you haven't specified when mocking.

```
public HrbContext(DbContextOptions<HrbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
{
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Moq needs a public default constructor when mocking, or you need to create the mock object with the constructor parameters.

Since you are already mocking the return value of `_repository.GetAsync`, you don't really need any real implementation inside the `DbContext` as it won't even be called.

In this case, as we don't want to mock or need the real implementation of `DbContextOptions<HrbContext>` or `IHttpContextAccessor`, pass them as `null`.

```
_context = new Mock<HrbContext>(null, null);
```

If you do need them (in other tests etc.), either mock them too or pass real instances through:

```
var options = new DbContextOptions<HrbContext>(...);
var httpContextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor(...);
_context = new Mock<HrbContext>(options, httpContextAccessor);
```

Comment: My solution indeed was : 

_context = new Mock<HrbContext>(new DbContextOptions<HrbContext>(), new HttpContextAccessor());

Comment: Wonderful - also since you're really not using the context for testing the service, I would just use null; I would also initialise the service once in the constructor and then use the 1 instance across the tests as it won't be multi-threaded etc.  - that'll keep your test clean and lean - you're welcome!

Comment: Thanks! If you want, I have a new issue now regarding testing & extension methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69527059/how-to-properly-mock-extension-methods-with-generics-in-xunit .